# RabbitVCS with Xubuntu

Tags: subversion, xubuntu

I'm trying to install RabbitVCS with this basic tut [>link<](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/install/ubuntu). The installation finished with no problems but after the logout/in my thunar (data manager) is not working any more. Any suggestions or tips. Is there a better GUI svn client for linux? thanks for any help

Comment: Can you show us any relevant command-line output?

Comment: no output. just a blank thunar window...

Answer (score 0):

I've got it set up following the same guidelines however I also installed `nautilus` and the `rabbitvcs-nautilus3`. I believe the thunar variant did not work in my case. After that either logout-login or reboot.

RabbitVCS is excellent once you get it working.